# CSS, Trying to center element but its children are not the same size

Tags: html, css, web, sass, css-grid

Hi guys so here is a picture of what I currently have

[image]

I have a grid of 3 rows and 3 columns(each column is min-content)
and I centered the elements in each cell.
It looks okay but if my title gets a lot bigger the space between the switch and the categories become way too big:

[image]

now I tried making the middle row inside a div container and using flex but then the elements won't center right because one category size is bigger than the other.

I also tried making the categories size the same but then when I go about centering the entire component somewhere on the page it goes too much to the right because of the white space the smaller category has.

Any idea how to make that space to be a lot smaller but keep the switch exactly in the middle of the title and button?

Heres the code:

The HTML:

```html
<div class="category-switch">
  <div class="form-check category-switch__btn">
    <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" />
    <label class="form-check-label form-label">Disable</label>
  </div>
  <div class="category-switch__switch">
    <div class="switch">
      <div class="form-check">
        <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" />
        <label class="form-check-label form-label"></label>
      </div>
      <span class="switch__slider switch__round"></span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <span class="category-switch__category category-switch__category--1">Male</span>
  <span class="category-switch__category category-switch__category--2">Female</span>
  <span class="category-switch__title">gender</span>
</div>
```

And the scss code:

```scss
.category-switch {
    // The grid to place the items
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(3, min-content);
    grid-template-rows: repeat(3, min-content);
    gap: 0.8rem;
    place-items: center;
    justify-items: center;
    // Makes the component be the width of its content
    width: max-content;

    // Title
    &__title {
        grid-row: 1/2;
        grid-column: 2/3;
        font-weight: bold;
        text-transform: capitalize;
    }

    // Placing category text
    &__category {
        &--1 {
            grid-row: 2/3;
            grid-column: 1/2;
        }

        &--2 {
            grid-row: 2/3;
            grid-column: 3/4;
        }
    }

    // The switch position
    &__switch {
        grid-row: 2/3;
        grid-column: 2/3;
    }

    // The button css
    &__btn {
        grid-row: 3/4;
        grid-column: 2/3;
        display: grid;
        place-items: center;
        position: relative;
        width: 7rem;
        height: 2.8rem;
        background: #d02b2b;
        border-radius: 0.5rem;
    }
}
```

tried to make the code as minimal as possible and removed some of the not related to positioning scss.

Comment: Please  show us the relevant code. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example My guess is you aren't getting the first row to span all columns.

Comment: @AHaworth hi, just added the code, and I am not letting the first-row span across all of the columns because if I do that it will not exactly center the title to my wishes because the categories are not the same size as the center of the row won't be exactly above and centered the button and switch elements.

Comment: Instead of centering the true/false Male/Female make those cells text-align right/left and include some padding.

Comment: @Michel hi, it won't solve the problem because the title makes the column of the switch bigger and that causes the big space between the categories to the switch.

Comment: You could try to have the swith with `position: absolute` and add some padding to the label. (half of the switch width)

Answer (score 0):

Before the edit I have write this...
So sorry if the class-names are different.
This is just a template.

```css
        #mainContainer{
            display:grid;
            grid-template-columns: 100px fit-content(10%) 100px;
            column-gap: 20px;
            grid-row-gap: 20px;
            /* adjust your template here */
        }
        #mainContainer div{
            display:grid;
            align-content: center;
            justify-content: center;
            border:1px solid #000000;
        }
        .top{
            font-size:1.6em;
            font-weight: bold;
            grid-column-start: 1;
            grid-column-end: 4;
            grid-row-start: 1;
            grid-row-end: 1;
        }
        .left{
            font-size:1.6em;
            font-weight: bold;
        }
        .right{
            font-size:1.6em;
            font-weight: bold;
        }
        .bottom{
            background-color: orangered;
            border-radius: 10px;
            height:30px;
        }
```

```html
    <div id="mainContainer">
        <div class="top">
            Neque porro quisquam est qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit
        </div>
        <div class="left">
            male
        </div>
        <div class="center">
            <img src="https://dummyimage.com/100x30/a6a6a6/fff" alt="image">
        </div>
        <div class="right">
            female
        </div>
        <div></div>
        <div class="bottom">
            Disable
        </div>
        <div></div>
    </div>
```

I hope that it can help.
Have a nice day.

Comment: Hi there @tatactic thanks for the answer.
your code has the same problem I am having, if the header is big the middle element width expands and the space between the categories to the middle element also expands.
also as I don't know the width of the categories I can't set an exact width otherwise it could overflow.

Comment: SRY bro, but without the code it was difficult to understand your issue @Matan